# Dividing an int by a float that is 0

Tags: c#

In the following code first I divide an int to a float that is a zero and get "∞" as the output then I divide an int by an int that is a zero and get an exception which is totally expected.

Could you please tell me thoroughly why do i get "∞" when I divide by zero that is a float?
I am guessing this has something to do with the way a floating point number is encoded. I would like to have a technical explanation, please.

```
float hh = 0;
int ff = 4;
Console.WriteLine(ff/hh);

int hh1 = 0;
int ff1 = 4;
Console.WriteLine(ff1 / hh1);
```

Comment: From the fine manual: "Dividing a floating-point value by zero doesn't throw an exception; it results in positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number (NaN), according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic. Because the following example uses floating-point division rather than integer division, the operation does not throw a DivideByZeroException exception." (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=net-6.0 )

Comment: Why do you get "∞": Because it is defined that way.

Comment: `ff / hh` (`ff == 4f`, `hh = 0`) will be turned into `ff / (float) hh` which is `float.PositiveInfinity`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [gnu libc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html):

> IEEE 754 floating point numbers can represent positive or negative infinity, and NaN (not a number). These three values arise from calculations whose result is undefined or cannot be represented accurately.

When using a float it will give you a positive or a negative infinity and this is for, from my understanding, better representation. Reading the gnu libc manual will most likely be more coherent and understandable than I can be in this answer so I urge you to check it out.

Comment: The gnu libc manual is not the first place I would look for a C# issue, but in this case the math is the same

Comment: Both use IEEE 754 though, although it's not a first place to search its extensive and provides the proper and correct information